# Get keyboard (PS/2) scan code set, using asm

Tags: assembly, keyboard, wdm

I would like to get my keyboard current scan code set.
Code that I am using looks more or less like this:

```
#define STATUSPORT 64h
#define DATAPORT 60h
#define PS2controllerOutputFull 0x20
#define PS2controllerInputFull 2h

void sendByte()
{
    __asm
    {
        push eax
    repeat :
        in al, STATUSPORT
        test al, PS2controllerInputFull
        jne repeat
        pop eax
        out DATAPORT, al
        clc
    }
}

UCHAR getByte()
{
    __asm
    {
    repeat:
        in al, STATUSPORT
        test al, PS2controllerOutputFull
        jne repeat
        in al, DATAPORT
        clc
    }
}

UCHAR getScanCodeSet()
{
    __asm
    {
        mov al, 0xF0
        call sendByte

        mov al, 0x00
        call sendByte

        call getByte
        cmp al, 0xFA
        jne unknownError

        call getByte; AL = Scan Code Set
        jmp exit

    unknownError:
        mov al, 0xDD

    exit:
    }
}
```

Instead of getting current control set number I receive 0xFA from keyboard(Acknowledge). I'd be very grateful for any suggestions.

(I ran this code from windows driver)

Comment: Shoouldn't SendByte look at OutputBufferFull and  GetByte look at InputBufferFull?

Comment: Hmm, even if it's wrong, this check passes and I end getting ack. Maybe I should read the result from other port?

Comment: I would look at the disassembly of your generated object files.  The compiler could be inserting additional unwanted instructions after your `__asm` blocks that trash the return value.  This is what [`__declspec( naked )`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/21d5kd3a.aspx) is for.

Comment: Also, you're running this as a driver in a *running* windows system? Did you ever consider you may be conflicting with the kernel who is also interacting with the keyboard controller?

Comment: The compiled code is ok (checked it while debugging in windbg). I can easilly change IRQL or clear interrupts, I am more curious how to correctly implement sending and receiving result of this command. Should I send a command to disable keyboard firstly, add some timeout... ?

Comment: So your question is not about coding in assembly but rather about how to use PS/2 keyboard protocol? In the later case Google query: `ps/2 keyboard protocol` seems to be the way to go

Comment: I wanted to know how to get current control set. I found the documentation, it said something like: 
"Writing 0xf0 (to 0x60) followed by 0 queries the mode, resulting in a scancode byte 43, 41 or 3f"

I found similar samples, but I end getting ACK. I would like to know if this code should work (but let's say it doesn't because it's interfering with Windows internals), or am I missing some other necessary commands?